How does “se” change the meaning?

I loved my boy from the moment he opened his eyes to the moment you closed them

is translated into the following

Amé a mi hijo desde el momento que abrió los ojos hasta el momento en que tú se los cerraste.

I know reflexive verbs are used in passive construction, but in this case we know who the agent is that is doing the closing of the eyes. Why would “se” be used and how would its omission change the meaning of the sentence?
Cheers

Se es una 'palabra vacía' que cumple diversas funciones. En este caso, actúa de complemento indirecto. Normalmente, se usaría 'le(s)', pero debido a que la oración tiene pronombres de objetos directos e indirectos, el indirecto va antes y cambian a 'se' para evitar la cacofonía. Entonces, significaría literalmente '*tú le los cerraste', pero decir eso suena muy lelo―esa palabra habrá surgido de lo mal que se lleva le con lo cuando están juntos xd?―entonces es 'tú se los cerraste'. El 'los' refiere a 'los ojos' (OD) y el 'se (le)' refiere al hijo (OI).
Ahora qué pasa si lo sacamos? En este caso particular, nada, porque se entiende que los ojos se refieren siempre a los del hijo. Entonces ambas son equivalentes, con o sin el se. Para poner a prueba la necesidad del se, lo más fácil es buscar otros tipos de verbos en donde pueda darse la ambigüedad.

―Al final enviaste esos papeles a tu amigo? 
―Ya los entregué. (es decir, al correo o a algún tercero)

o:

―Ya se los entregué. (es decir, se los di en mano porque lo vi en algún lado)

Obviamente, hay verbos en donde siempre debería ir el complemento directo. Un ejemplo es dar, en donde no sería aceptable o al menos muy dudoso decir '*Ya los di.' a secas porque confundiría mucho; sería 'ya di los papeles al correo' o 'ya se los di (a mi amigo)'.
